# Fonts are not loading in Windows Server 2016, Windows 10 in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I'm working on Windows Server 2016 Windows 10, In IE fonts are not loading showing unknown errors as you can see in below image. Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below article is relevant to same problem.

https://medium.com/@zikaitoh/css3111-and-css3114-issue-640e7d5e9163